# Error en Codigo PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];

$query_estado = "INSERT INTO estados_clientes(sigla) VALUES('$estado')";

$adicionar_estado = mysqli_query($connection, $query_estado);

if ($adicionar_estado) {

mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE estados_clientes SET nombre = (SELECT estados.nombre FROM estados WHERE estados.sigla = '$estado') ORDER BY estados_clientes.id DESC LIMIT 1");

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO ciudades_clientes(ciudades_clientes.nombre) VALUES('$cidade'");

mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE ciudades_clientes SET ciudades_clientes.id_estados_clientes = (SELECT estados_clientes.id FROM estados_clientes ORDER BY estados_clientes.id DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY ciudades_clientes.id DESC LIMIT 1");

}

?>
```

Tengo el siguiente problema este codigo lo comprobe en MYSQL y funciona sin problemas pero en PHP falla.

Esta el `$query_estado = "INSERT INTO estados_clientes(sigla) VALUES('$estado')";`  Esto toma el valor de las siglas de un estado es decir "Amazonas" entonces sus siglas son AM, eso es lo que inserta ahi.

en el siguiente codigo `mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE estados_clientes SET nombre = (SELECT estados.nombre FROM estados WHERE estados.sigla = '$estado') ORDER BY estados_clientes.id DESC LIMIT 1");`

Aquí entro a una tabla con todo los estados en ella tanto su nombre como sus siglas `estados`.
Lo que hago es que me compare la variable `$estados`  y me busque una coincidencia en las siglas dentro de la tabla `estados` y si es asi me hara un `UPDATE` en la tabla `estados_clientes` por lo tanto coloco `ORDER BY estados_clientes.id DESC LIMIT 1`
para que me tome el ultimo valor insertado de la tabla `estados_clientes`

Quiero hacer lo mismo con estas lineas de codigo `mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO ciudades_clientes(ciudades_clientes.nombre) VALUES('$cidade'");`

`mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE ciudades_clientes SET ciudades_clientes.id_estados_clientes = (SELECT estados_clientes.id FROM estados_clientes ORDER BY estados_clientes.id DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY ciudades_clientes.id DESC LIMIT 1");`

Pero el `mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO ciudades_clientes(ciudades_clientes.nombre) VALUES('$cidade'");`

No funciona es decir no realiza el `INSERT` pero el `UPDATE` sin funciona y por lo tanto siempre me modifica el ultimo registro de la tabla `ciudades_clientes`

Comment: Esta parte `ORDER BY ciudades_clientes.id DESC LIMIT 1` hace que siempre se actualice el último registro, deberías usar un filtro, por ejemplo `WHERE ciudades_clientes.id = ?`, cambiando el signo de interrogación por el ID del registro que realmente quieres actualizar.

Comment: @Triby, Si te entiendo pero eso sucede por quiero que lo haga si el ```INSERT``` funcionara me haría ese cambio en el ultimo dato agregado y no en lo pre-existentes

Comment: Para eso existe [mysqli_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: @Triby, No se como funciona eso, pero aqui el problema es esto ```mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO ciudades_clientes(ciudades_clientes.nombre) VALUES('$cidade'"); ```

Comment: Por favor no dupliques preguntas. Tienes [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/514264/54039) sobre el mismo tema y solo complicas el recibir una ayuda adecuada. Haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas cómo funciona la plataforma.

Comment: Previendo que "no sabes cómo funciona eso" te puse un enlace, consúltalo o vas a seguir sin saber.

Comment: @Triby No puede devolver el ID del ultimo ```INSERT``` si este no funciona, mi problema es ese ```INSERT```

Comment: Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/514290/edit) para agregar el código que intentaste y no te funcionó, solo así puedes mejorar las posibilidades de obtener una buena respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

tienes que tomar el resultado del select y guardarlo en una variable ejemplo

```
 $cidade = $row["cidade"];
```

luego pasarla la siguiente consulta que estas realizando

Comment: pero la varible ```$cidade``` la traigo por metodo POST

Comment: mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO ciudades_clientes(ciudades_clientes.nombre) VALUES('$cidade')");

la comilla y el parentesis esta mal bro

Comment: Acabo de comprobarlo el ```INSERT``` sigue sin funcionar me sigue alterado el ultimo dato de la tabla ```ciudades_clientes```